# Como formatar `DateTime?` no formato dd/mm/yyyy usando Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, conversão, linq-to-entities

Tenho a `query` abaixo, mas ao tenta formata o campo `Data_nascimento` e `Data_exclusao` com o `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` me retorna o um erro em tempo de execução.

> O método 'System.String ToString(System.String)' não tem conversões
> suportadas em SQL.

```
var dependentes = (from dependentes in ctx.Tabela_DocsItens
                    where itens.Controle == dependentes.Controle_titular
                    select new listaDependentes
                    {
                         carteirinhaSegurado = dependentes.Cod_identific,
                         nomeSegurado = dependentes.Segurado,
                         dataNascimento = dependentes.Data_nascimento.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                         dataExclusao = dependentes.Data_exclusao.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    }).ToList();
```

Existe alguma forma de converte isso antes de materializar o objeto, ou seja lança para o banco de dados uma `query` que retorne os campos de dados no formato que eu quero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível, pois o Entity não consegue traduzir o `ToString(format)` para uma função `Sql`, Então será necessário executar a consulta sem formatar a data, para somente então formatar a data.

```
var dependentes = (
    from dependentes in ctx.Tabela_DocsItens
    where itens.Controle == dependentes.Controle_titular
    select new {
        carteirinhaSegurado = dependentes.Cod_identific,
        nomeSegurado = dependentes.Segurado,
        dataNascimento = dependentes.Data_nascimento,
        dataExclusao = dependentes.Data_exclusao,
    }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new listaDependentes {
        carteirinhaSegurado = x.carteirinhaSegurado,
        nomeSegurado = x.nomeSegurado,
        dataNascimento = x.dataNascimento?.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") ?? String.Empty,
        dataExclusao = x.dataExclusao?.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") ?? String.Empty,
    }).ToList();
```

Só um pequeno detalhe, você estava acessando o `Value` sem verificar o `HasValue`, então caso `Data_nascimento` ou `Data_exclusao` sejam nulos, você teria um erro em tempo de execução.

No exemplo acima, este problema foi sanado usando a sintaxe do `C#6`, caso esteja usando uma versão anterior, terá de usar um operador ternário.

Comment: Tem alguma diferença seu eu usar ToList() no lugar de                     ..AsEnumerable() ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza a ideia do `AsEnumerable`neste ponto é apenas para forçar a consulta com o `Banco de Dados`, como a única coisa a ser feita como esta lista é percorrer a mesma, então não há a necessidade de uma `List<listaDependentes>`, mas isto é apenas uma microotimização, então não precisa se preocupar com isto.

Comment: OK, obrigado...

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza adicionei uma nota sobre o acesso as Datas.

Comment: Boa dica, não sabia dessa.

Comment: Só uma correção, o certo é .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), com o mm retorna 00. ou seja 17/00/2016